# O comando Select do MySql diferencia números que possuem zero a esquerda?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela no `MySql` que possui um campo chamado `Codigo`, do tipo `varchar(20)`, esse campo no caso aceita códigos que possuem `zero` a esquerda e códigos que não possuem `zero` a esquerda.

Exemplo:

```
Códigos 000123 e 321
```

Quando eu faço o SELECT dessa forma:

`SELECT * FROM Codigos WHERE Codigo LIKE '123'`

Ele não me retorna o código `000123`. 
Gostaria de saber como posso fazer esse SELECT.

Comment: O problema real é que você está gravando números como texto (varchar). Em texto, "1" e "01" são diferentes.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Codigos WHERE 0 + Codigo = 123` - é gambiarra para "consertar" o problema que o @bfavaretto já mencionou. O correto é arrumar o DB. Se precisa dos zeros, controle na exibição, em vez de armazenar.

Comment: Obrigado, no caso vou arrumar no BD então, já que só tenho que armazenar números inteiros, e no caso eu padronizo para não ser usado os Zero a esquerda! assim fica mais fácil para mim tratar depois.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema, como mencionado pelo @bfavaretto nos comentários, é que provavelmente você está armazenando seus dados numéricos como *strings*.

Além disso, se busca valores exatos, o operador é o `=` e não o `LIKE`.

Uma possível solução é:

```
SELECT * FROM Codigos WHERE CAST(Codigo AS UNSIGNED) = 123;
```

(use `SIGNED` se tiver números negativos)

Ou mesmo:

```
SELECT * FROM Codigos WHERE 0 + Codigo = 123
```

mas isto não deveria ser usado definitivamente, se seus dados forem sempre numéricos ou nulos.

### ZEROFILL

Vale notar que você pode criar colunas numéricas com prefixo `0` usando a opção `ZEROFILL`, é uma das opções de coluna do MySQL. Neste caso, basta não usar aspas:

```
SELECT Codigo FROM Codigos WHERE Codigo = 123
```

Resultado, supondo que a coluna seja definida como `INT(6) ZEROFILL`:

> ```
> 000123
> ```

Mais detalhes no [manual do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)<sup>(en)</sup>.

Comment: Obrigado, no caso vou arrumar no BD então, já que só tenho que armazenar números inteiros, e no caso eu padronizo para não ser usado os Zero a esquerda! assim fica mais fácil para mim tratar depois.

Answer (score 1):

Tente este código:

```
Select * from Codigos where Codigo LIKE '%123';
```

`%` Pega zero ou mais caracteres

`–` Pega somente um caractere

Alguma dúvida mais avise, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado, no caso vou arrumar no BD então, já que só tenho que armazenar números inteiros, e no caso eu padronizo para não ser usado os Zero a esquerda! assim fica mais fácil para mim tratar depois.